# Validation fails if am using user-select: none; in CSS

Tags: css

I have a css file from a jquery plugin. In the file I found this css but the validator does not validate it. Can anyone explain what the use of this type of css is, and if there are any alternatives?

```
div.rateit
{
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

Comment: Do you have anything against Google? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a question which is easy to google

Comment: @dTDesign Title was misleading, he was looking for something else, now fixed :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Ah, okay. Now i see :) But can't undo the flag...

Comment: @dTDesign it's k, flag will be either disputed or rejected :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *won't be able to select the content* inside `div` having class `rateit`. Support is kinda buggy, so if you are looking to block the selection in a better way, consider using JavaScript(Even JS will fail if user has JS turned off).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nFKbN/)

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

Support for [`user-select`](http://caniuse.com/user-select-none)

---

As you commented, I've already shared MDN link in my answer, if you see at very top, it says **NON-STANDARD**, in other words, w3c has yet not accepted this property as a standard and hence your validation fails.

---

To explain you in a bit detail, think like W3C validator has a sheet of rules, these rules have a list of Standard properties, so when you validate your file, validator will go through these rules, those which are not in the list will be marked as invalid. So even if the properties work in the browser, doesn't mean they are a part of the Standard, but can be accepted later. This also means that properties which doesn't validate doesn't mean they wont work. It's just that the property is not a part of the standard, and I recommend you to use `proprietary` declarations for such properties like `-moz` and `-webkit` until the property is accepted as a part of standard.